# how to remove a word inside json url by the code?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-json

I heve a json url:
http://wach.ma/mobile/item.php?id=15236

i want to parse the content and show it in a recyclerview.

everything is good, but when i run it this error happens:

Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

inside my json file there is a word i want to remove it by the code (because i can't edit the resource)

```
Array <------------//i want to remove this word
{"articles" : [{"name":"fiat uno ",
"description":"fiat uno 
model2002",
"price":"32000dh",
"seen":"5",
"username":"Kech",
"picture":"http:\/\/www.wach.ma\/files\/pictures\/1508420901.png",
"city":"Marrakech",
"phone":"0666353083"}]}
```

my activity where i want to do that:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String URL_DATA = "http://wach.ma/mobile/item.php?
id=15236";

private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListDetail> listDetails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    recyclerView2= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
    recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listDetails=new ArrayList<>();
    loadRecyclerViewData();
}
private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject2=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array=jsonObject2.getJSONArray("articles");
                for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    ListDetail item = new ListDetail(
                            o.getString("picture"),
                            o.getString("name"),
                            o.getString("city"),
                            o.getString("username"),
                            o.getString("price"),
                            o.getString("phone"),
                            o.getString("description")
                    );
                    listDetails.add(item);
                }
                adapter = new DetailAdapter(listDetails, 
getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

i'm sorry for my bad english.
thanks in advance

Comment: `String.substring`

Comment: you just remove it from your php API. Why make patches in your Java code.

Comment: @Krups i can't edit the resource

Comment: @Selvin how can i use this and where?

Comment: Obviously before parsing but @Krups comment is better

Comment: @Hamiprogrammer check my ans this is work as charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string replace method as and replace the word array and replace it with an empty `String` and hence use, Check if your method logic looks like this code you also have alternatives String methods like "`replace()`,`substring()`, or finding the index of `"{"` but always `trim()` first (remove spaces at the beginning and end of your `String`):

```
try {
            String new_string=response.trim().substring(5);
            JSONObject jsonObjectRoot=new JSONObject(new_string);
            JSONArray jsonArrayArticles=jsonObjectRoot.getJSONArray("articles");
            for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++) {
                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                ListDetail item = new ListDetail(  
       ....// Your more code here
```

Comment: where can i use it please?

Comment: On response check I have edited the question remove the "Array" word  will  remove it in response! let me add more code

Comment: Have you see that part in your code @Hamiprogrammer??

Comment: `{ .... "username" : "Array" ... }` and you are doomed ... please, stop posting replace as an answer because it's wrong!!!

Comment: Why? is it wrong? check his response here in his question http://wach.ma/mobile/item.php?id=15236  the string has to miss the Array thing!

Comment: @Xenolion it's not worked and JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(newString);                   jsonObject variable is never used

Comment: @Selvin please reconsider and remove your downvote check his link http://wach.ma/mobile/item.php?id=15236 the response should have "Array" word removed!

Comment: Lol ... and any "Array" in the response ... so fx http://wach.ma/mobile/item.php?id=15237 may can contains "Array" in some field and will be removed ...

Comment: @Selvin please how can i fix that? put your reponse as an answer to vote it

Comment: @Hamiprogrammer check my ans

Comment: I have updated my answer @Hamiprogrammer It will work. If not send your logs so as to trace the bug!

Comment: Visited your profile and I start laughing when you said you like downvoting too much @Selvin . Why? Can we chat?

Comment: Okay @Hamiprogrammer NOW you will have to put a tick in my answer and accept it as it has solved your problem. You are the only one in the world who can do that because you asked the question!! In the left of the MY answer you fill the option to put a tick (stack_overflow_rule). **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: @Selvin as you can see above. The user who asked the question is happy with my answer (although he does not know how to accept it) please reconsider your downvote in my answer for future users!

Comment: Oooh I have seen it, Thank you and **Happy Coding!** @Hamiprogrammer

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `substring()`

```
String newJSON=response.substring(5);
JSONObject jsonObject2=new JSONObject(newJSON);
JSONArray array=jsonObject2.getJSONArray("articles");
```

Comment: `{ .... "username" : "Array" ... }` and you are doomed ... please, stop posting replace as an answer because it's wrong!!!

Comment: @Selvin didn't get u'

Comment: *didn't get u'* Yeah, I know ... that's why you don't now why it's a wrong answer ... replace will replace every "Array" occurrence which is wrong

Comment: I've already wrote .... What if "username" will be "Array" (or link will be contains Array or whatever? Just think: after your code it will be ""(or wrong link)

Comment: *`response.substring(0,5);`* Still wrong ... now newJSON is "Array" and nothing more ... but you are on good track

Comment: This is the most funny person I have ever met in stackOverflow. Although he know the answer. He does not answer a question it but waiting and downvoting others seriously. He also downvoted mine too. I like him! @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to invalid json string.

always truncate whitespace and other text before and after curly brackets of json string...

This way you can do this.

```
 String new_string = response.trim().substring(response.indexOf('{'), 
 response.lastIndexOf('}'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove the invalid json variable from your code. Try to parse json in a valid format